# How to covert array of objects to array of key-value pairs?

Tags: php, arrays, laravel

I got an array of objects from Laravel query builder:

```
[
 {
   "name": "John",
   "code": "006"
 },
 {
   "name": "James"
   "code": "007"
 },
 {
   "name": "Jone"
   "code": "008"
 }
]
```

I wanna turn it into this:

```
[
  "John"  => "006",
  "James" => "007",
  "Jone"  => "008"
]
```

Comment: can you share that laravel code ?

Answer (score 3):

If you have an array:

```
\Illuminate\Support\Arr::pluck($array, 'code', 'name');
array_pluck($array, 'code', 'name');
```

If you have a collection:

```
$collection->pluck('code', 'name');
```

You could have also plucked from the query:

```
$query->pluck('code', 'name'); // instead of the `get` call
```

*Depending upon Laravel version this method could be `lists`*

[Laravel 5.6 Docs - Helpers - array_pluck](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/helpers#method-array-pluck)

[Laravel 5.6 Docs - Collections - Method pluck](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/collections#method-pluck)

[Laravel 5.6 Docs - Query Builder - Retrieving Results](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/queries#retrieving-results)

Comment: `pluck` will work too. Just need to comver the json string first.

Answer (score 2):

You can try this -

```
// decode the json
$data = json_decode($array, true);
$final = array_column($data, "code", "name");
```

`json_decode` will decode the JSON string and return array.

[array_column](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-column.php) will return the values for provided keys.

Comment: For that case it will never work. Then may be an sub array.

Comment: You don't need to use array_column twice or array_combine. `$final = array_column($data, "code", "name");` is the same as your code.

Comment: Totally forgot the third parameter. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If there is multiple persons with the same name you can't use array_combine.

This method uses array_intersect to find the codes that match the name and create a subarray on each name whith all the codes.

```
$arr = json_decode($str, true);
$names = array_column($arr, "name");
$codes = array_column($arr, "code");

foreach(array_unique($names) as $name){
    $new[$name] = array_intersect_key($codes, array_intersect($names, [$name]));
}
var_dump($new);
```

output:

```
array(3) {
  ["John"]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    string(3) "006"
    [3]=>
    string(3) "010"
  }
  ["James"]=>
  array(1) {
    [1]=>
    string(3) "007"
  }
  ["Jone"]=>
  array(1) {
    [2]=>
    string(3) "008"
  }
}
```

https://3v4l.org/Tj4Dd